# Wordpress two sites in different folders - redirecting issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have two Wordpress websites, one is in root and another in subfolder.
**example.com** and **example.com/newsite**

When I open example.com/newsite/ all is working good, but if I open any pages likes

`example.com/newsite/about` or `example.com/newsite/contact`

browser auto redirect to

`example.com/about` and `example.com/contact`

I changed all paths, address, home url in config and sql to example.com/newsite/

**Root htacess looks like:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

htaccess for /newsite looks same.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a different rewritebase if it's in a sub directory. Your wordpress rules in side htaccess under /newsite should look something like this.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```